# TypeError: 'set' object is not callable discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I alway get a TypeError:

### Error

File "D:Discord-Bot/bot.py", line 21, in 
async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

### Code

```py
#bot.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', help_command=None)

@client.commands
async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    await user.add_role(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Sucsessfully given {role.mention} to {user.mention} ")
client.run(bottocken)
```

Comment: By the way please include the solution in an answer. Don't edit `[solved]` into your title.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

change `@client.commands` to `@client.command()`

### Explanation

What you want to use is the [Bot.command()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command) decorator. Which adds a commands to the bot.

[Bot.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands) is a set of [discord.ext.commands.Command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) (ie `Set[discord.ext.commands.Command]`) & a set object is not a callable (i.e not a decorator)